# Measuring Low Resistance using Kelvin Setup. The four terminals are F+,F-,S+,S-

Tags: voltage

Kelvin setup consists of four terminals F+,F-,S+,S-. My setup forces current of 100mA into F+,F- and measure voltage at S+,S- . I use keithley 2400 to measure voltage at S+ and then at S-. I will then take difference between S+ and S- and then then divide by the force current to give me the resistance value. But some time I measure S+ lower than S-. What could be the probable reason. One example is 1.479E+0,1.482E+0,-29.760E-3, S+=1.479E+0, S-=1.482E+0, Diff=-29.760E-3 Raw Data. Kelvin setup should give me readins which are consistent, but I measureing resistances for some dies are higher and some dies are negative. I using a probe card,which measures this resistance on a wafer. What could be the probable reasons. Probecard pin, pad interaction with probe card pins? The connections to F+,F-,S+,S- are thus. F+ is connected to + of SMU1,F- is connected to +of SMU2. SMU1 forces current, SMU2 is set to 0 volts to set as return or gnd point. S+, S- are measured with Keithley 2400

I expect the resistance to be around 20-30 milli ohms. I have another probe card which gives me consistent readings. This probecard was repaired a few days ago. Could it be that debris from the pad is deposited over time on the pin(and which is difficult to remove) and cause this variation?. But I am more interested to know why S- reads higher than S+,though it is a kelvin/four-point measurement setup.

Kindly help me to find the answers to my problem.

Comment: Are you sure all four probes are making good contact?

Comment: Can you visually inspect the area where the repairs were made? Soldering commonly uses flux to clean the metallic contact areas, but if the flux was not fully cleaned away it can leave a slightly conductive residue. (On the order of a few mega-Ohms)

Comment: You have the luxury of a working one and a problem one side by side, compare them. Rule of thumb in electronics, it's always the connections, the contact points. Well, nearly always.

Comment: Thank you All, for taking time and responding to my queries.To make things more clear, I am using a probe card to test a wafer.

Comment: Hearth : I checked the probe marks, they look fine to me, clear.  
MarkU : I am probing a wafer with a probe card, so there is no soldering involved
Neil : Well noted. I too noted that.  
My question again : Why would a S- measure higher voltage than S+.  this will give me a -ve resistance. some probable causes : Poor contact, noise, measurement delay etc.  I really need to find the answer to this dilemma